# Optimization problem with definite integral inequality constraints

Tags: co.combinatorics, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, inequalities, integration

**Question:** How can we prove that there exists a real constant $c\ge 1$ such that the following inequality holds for all integers $d>1$ and all real numbers $r\in\left[1,\sqrt{d}\right]$?

$$\int_{-1}^1 \left(\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\right)^{d-1} dx\le c\cdot \frac{r^d}{\sqrt{d-1}}$$

---

(*Furthermore, is it also possible to find an upper bound for the minimum value of $c\in [1,\infty)$ such that the above inequality holds for all $d>1$ and all $r\in\left[1,\sqrt{d}\right]$?*)

Comment: I get that your integral is less than $2r^{d-1}$ for all $r \ge1$. Just estimate the integrand with $r^{d-1}$.

Comment: Just estimate the LHS by $r^{d-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\{-(d-1)\frac{x^2}{2r^2}\}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{r^d}{\sqrt{d-1}}$.

Comment: Thank you @GiorgioMetafune. This way, whan $r$ is small (say constant), we get $c$ depending on $d$, and we do not get that the inequality holds for a constant $c$ and for all $d>1$ and all $r\in\left[1,\sqrt{d}\right]$.

Comment: Thank you once again @fedja! This is precisely consistent with what I was expecting to obtain!

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the questione, sorry.

Comment: @fedja how much can be the LHS different from this estimate?

Comment: Looks like just constant number of times, i.e., there is a lower bound of the same type in the range you are interested in.

Comment: Than you @fedja!

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica answers

```
NMaximize[{Integrate[(r^2 - x^2)^(d/2 - 1/2), {x, -1, 1}, 
Assumptions -> d > 1 && r >= 1]/r^d*Sqrt[d - 1], 
r >= 1 && r <= Sqrt[d] && d > 1 && d \[Element] Integers},{r, d}]
```

$$\{2.43959,\{r\to 1.01254,d\to 28\}\} $$
and

```
NMaximize[{Integrate[(r^2 - x^2)^(d/2 - 1/2), {x, -1, 1}, 
Assumptions -> d > 1 && r >= 1]/r^d*Sqrt[d - 1], 
 r >= 1 && r <= Sqrt[d] && d > 1}, {r, d}, AccuracyGoal -> 4,PrecisionGoal -> 4]
```

$$ \{2.50662,\{r\to 149.294,d\to 611671.\}\}$$

Addition. The command of Maple confirms it by

```
restart;Digits := 20;DirectSearch:-Search((d, r) -> int((r^2 - x^2)^(1/2*d - 1/2),x = -1 .. 1, numeric, epsilon = 1/1000)*sqrt(d - 1)/r^d, {1 <= d, 1 <= r, r <= sqrt(d)}, maximize);
```

$$[ 2.5066284493892445574, \left[ \begin {array}{c} 
 280247431.41221862419\\  1059.2785342279385942
\end {array} \right] ,317]
 $$ It seems the supremum is attained as $d \to \infty$ and $r \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! However I would like to prove it mathematically.

Comment: @Penelope Benenati: But this is math.

Comment: Elementary asymptotic estimates  give $\sqrt{2\pi}=2.506628274631$ for the constant.

Comment: Do you mean "asymptotic" w.r.t. $d,r\to\infty$? if so, how can you first mathematically prove that "the supremum is attained as $d,r\to\infty$"?

Comment: @Penelope Benenati: I think the asymptotics of the integral under consideration as $d\to\infty$ can be found by the Laplace's method. That asymptotics depends on $r$. According to numeric calculations, its maximum should be attained for $r\approx \sqrt d$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can we prove that the supremum for $c$ is attained exactly as $d\to\infty$?